# XML validation error when using multiple schema files/namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been reading a ton about xml and learning a lot but I am stuck on one error.

I have a schema defined in multiple files and I can't get it to work.  Here is an example

==================================

## libraryBooks.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="urn:MyNamespace"
  targetNamespace="urn:MyNamespace"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  >

  <xsd:element name="libraryBooks" type="libraryBooksType"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="libraryBooksType">
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

==================================

## book.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="urn:MyNamespace2"
  targetNamespace="urn:MyNamespace2"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  >

  <xsd:element name="book" type="booksType"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="bookType">
    <xsd:attribute name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

==================================

## myXml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <libraryBooks
     xmlns="urn:MyNamespace"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:MyNamespace file:///C:/libraryBooks.xsd"

     name="CentralLibrary">
     <mn2:book 
        xmlns:mn2="file:///C:/book.xsd"
        title="How to make xml work the way I want">
     </mn2:book>
  </libraryBooks>
```

So the error I get would be "The 'file:///C:/book.xsd:book' element is not found".
Any ideas?  I'm almost certain it is something simple

**Edit**:  Thank you so much everyone.  I was close but just stuck on one minor thing.  Really appreciate the direction.  I tried both methods and in case anyone else reading this is wondering, the way to enter multiple schemaLocations at the root node is

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:MyNamespace file:///C:/libraryBooks.xsd
                    urn:MyNamespace2 file:///C:/book.xsd"
```

Comment: In what language are you trying to parse the XML

Comment: I would try moving xmlns:mn2="file:///C:/book.xsd" to the top level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right for the first namespace, but for the second one, you somehow got the namespace URI and the schema location mixed up. Try this:

```
 <mn2:book 
    xmlns:mn2="urn:MyNamespace2"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:MyNamespace2 file:///C:/book.xsd"
    title="How to make xml work the way I want">
 </mn2:book>
```

... you can additionally move the `xmlns:mn2` and the `xsi:schemaLocation` up to the top level (similarly to what Grzenio suggested), if you want.